# How to work with apache Jmeter with ZK Framework

Tags: apache, jmeter, zk

I am new at performance testing and I would like to load 500 virtual users and check the response time of my application.

I want to use apache `jmeter` with ZK Framework.

Can you please help achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you've already resolved your problem or not, but the first thing you will need to do is download the relevant zk plugin (zk-jmeter-plugin-0.8.0.jar) available via http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2013/08/06/zk-jmeter-plugin/

save the plugin .jar to %apache-jmeter-root%/lib/ext

Once you've downloaded this, run JMeter.  Within the Workbench object in your JMeter hierarchy, there will be a new 'Non-Test Element' entitled 'ZK HTTP Proxy Server'.  You will need to use this rather than the standard JMeter 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' to record your http requests.

I'm new to JMeter and the ZK Framework myself, but I've just been working on this so hopefully this detail will be helpful.

There are some additional config files you will need once you actually get going, but I'll wait to see if you still need any more help before bombarding you with info you might already have.

Cheers,

sqeeky